# How to automatically copy text received from api which contains a link using javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i am trying to implement a feature in app which allows users to have text automatically copied to clipboard when a request is successfully processed but there are some problems when it comes to links in these texts.

I am trying to build a textarea to copy and use document.execCommand for that

```
copy(str) {
  const el = document.createElement('textarea');
  el.value = str;
  el.setAttribute('readonly', '');
  el.style.position = 'absolute';
  el.style.left = '-9999px';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.select();
  document.execCommand('copy');
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

In request context it looks something like this

```
async function submit() {
  this.$confirm({
    message: `Are you sure?`,
    button: {
      no: 'No',
      yes: 'Yes',
    },
    callback: async (confirm) => {
      if (confirm) {
        // loader
        const loader = this.$vs.loading({
          target: this.$refs.container,
          type: 'scale',
        });

        try {
          const res = await this.$axios.post('/api/run');

          try {
            this.$globals.copy(res.text);
          } catch (err) {
            console.error(err);
            this.$vs.notification({
              color: 'warning',
              position: 'top-right',
              title: 'Could not automatically copy',
            });
          }
        } catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
          this.$vs.notification({
            color: 'danger',
            position: 'top-right',
            duration: 120000,
            title: 'Error',
            text: err.response
              ? err.response.data.message
              : 'Failed to process the request',
          });
        } finally {
          loader.close();
        }
      }
    },
  });
}
```

The problem is that it won't copy the text on the background (when window is not focused, or other application is open) if it contains link, i have tested it couple of times and can confirm. I have also tried `navigator.writeText` but it wont copy when executed automatically and user should always be focused on the browser at the moment.

Comment: You can only use `execCommand('copy')` inside the eventhandler of a usertriggered event (like a mouseclick) ...

Comment: @derpirscher i know, when users click a button it sends a request and on response there's a text that i need to copy, the problem is whenever it contains text it fails to copy automatically

Comment: what do mean by `whenever it contains text it fails to copy automatically` you mean link?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure, whether the response of an ajax request (even if that request was triggered by a user action) is still considered as usertiggered event ..

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi sorry i meant link

Comment: @derpirscher it still works if there's no link

Comment: So you mean, it just doesn't copy text in the form of `https://example.com/?x=y` that seems rather strange behaviour ... Are you sure `data.text` contains the link as a string? Set a breakpoint in the first line of the `copy()` function and check the value and type of the `str` parameter

Comment: I don't think the problem with be link because you can simply check it by `textbox` and set link as a value of it and see working. I did this check and I copy link successfully

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi i think its because yours is calling the function mine is calling it as a callback

Comment: I updated the question where i show the entire request process. Its Vue.js btw but i dont think that should matter

Comment: Have you checked, that `copy()` in fact receives the correct value in `str`, ie `str` is in fact a string and contains the correct link? Because I don't think that `execCommand('copy')` somehow depends on the content of the string to copy ...

Comment: @derpirscher yes i did, it shows the correct text when i console log in the function, but still doesnt copy